# Bootstrap Order of Classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I am setting up my columns and starting mobile-first, do i HAVE to spell out every single column size as classes? Or will it take the smallest one and apply to all?

For ex, if I want a column to be 12 wide on xs, but 6 wide on everything up from there, do I have to:

```
 .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-6 .col-lg-6
```

OR, does it take the smallest one given, and use that for everything larger, ie:

```
 .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 (so everything sm and above would be 6)
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

**WHAT BOOTSTRAP SAYS:**

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present.

---

**SHORT ANSWER:**

> .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 (so everything sm and above would be 6)

---

**FURTHER EXPLANATION (GRID SYSTEM BREAKPOINTS):**

In **Bootstrap V3**, there are 4 breakpoints (xs, sm, md, lg), each of those represent a different [CSS media query](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) ***except*** for xs which has no media query since this is the default in Bootstrap,

EXAMPLE:

---

*Extra Small*

```
.col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

*Small*

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

*Medium*

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

*Large:*

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

---

This means that if you use col-sm-n, n representing a number from 1 to 12, and you do not specify md or lg, that will be applied to devices with 768px and above since that is what your media query applies.

**CODE SNIPPET**: *(Toggle full page and resize window)*

```css
.row [class^=col-],
.row [class*=col-] {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      col-sm-6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since the queries are applied using `min-width` and xs does not have a media query, using sm class without declaring an xs class will default to col-*-12 in devices smaller than 768px. There's no need to declare xs class unless you want your block elements to be less than 100% width in that viewport.

**CODE SNIPPET:** *(Toggle full page and resize window)*

```css
.row [class^=col-],
.row [class*=col-] {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      col-xs-6 col-sm-6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
 col-md-6
```

it will be 6 columns wide on larger to medium devices but in small it will be 12 columns wide

Comment: I think you mean `col-sm-6`. It's true, `col-xs-12` won't change anything because all it does is `width: 100%;` which is the default for block elements that don't have their width set.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb use col-md- `col-md-6` or `col-md-12` then if you have to add others add those. You shouldn't have to add all the column classes to all your divs. Start with mobile to desktop in the order as Bootstrap & all responsive design should be.